# C++ CLR will not compile outside of debug

Tags: c++, winforms, compilation, clr

I'm trying to build an application using clr, and am trying to compile it with Multi Threaded DLL (/MD), but it will not work.  It keeps giving me this:

```
WindowsFormsApplication3.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A000796) "extern "C" int __cdecl _CrtDbgReportW(int,wchar_t const *,int,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,...)" (?_CrtDbgReportW@@$$J0YAHHPB_WH00ZZ)
WindowsFormsApplication3.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A000797) "extern "C" int __cdecl _CrtDbgReportW(int,wchar_t const *,int,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,...)" (?_CrtDbgReportW@@$$J0YAHHPB_WH00ZZ)
WindowsFormsApplication3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __cdecl _CrtDbgReportW(int,wchar_t const *,int,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,...)" (?_CrtDbgReportW@@$$J0YAHHPB_WH00ZZ)
D:\Users\Student\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication3.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

It works just fine when I compile with /MDd.  I've looked up what the errors mean, but the problem is in a file I can't access.  Do I have other settings wrong or something?

EDIT: I figured it out.  _DEBUG was defined under Preprocessor Definitions in Properties.  Thank you Balog for your advice--I will have to reconsider how I'm doing some of this.  I apologize for not really knowing the finer points, this is my first application using a compiler other than gcc in a long time.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile your program for debug (i.e. _DEBUG defined) CRT may use code that calls that CrtDebugReport function. That is defined only in the debug version of the dll.

Certainly you could just drop in  a definition of the missing function to shut the linker up, but the normal way is to compile with consistent settings. Why do you try to force /MD instead of /MDd?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this and I acknowledge that I'm probably doing a lot of things wrong.  I want to make this so I can deploy it on other computers, which I assumed I needed to us /MD over debug.  I was also hoping it would at least make it easier to run on other computers.